# Rotate JFrame 180 degrees - get Graphics2d instance

Tags: java, swing, rotation, graphics2d, affinetransform

I have JFrame with something. I want to rotate it completely by 180 degrees. Problem is with accessing the correct graphics instance from class with JFrame, because its somehow called in zillion classes which are somehow injected, etc. So I won't probably have chance revrite paint method which is somehow ecapsulated in the core off the app.

```
float anchorx = configuration.getDisplayWidth() / 2.0f;//center x coord
float anchory = configuration.getDisplayHeight() / 2.0f;//center y coord

protected JFrame graphicalPosDisplayFrame;

graphicalPosDisplayFrame = new JFrame();

graphicalPosDisplayFrame.setLocation(configuration.getDisplayPositionX()+100, configuration.getDisplayPositionY()+500); //this works fine

//for rotate i tryed this, but i does not repaint it
graphicalPosDisplayFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDefaultTransform().rotate(Math.PI, anchorx, anchory);
graphicalPosDisplayFrame.repaint();
```

Here is example how to do it when you have Graphhics2d instance
http://www.coderanch.com/t/623829/GUI/java/rotate-JPanel
its the answer from Piet Souris posted 11/18/2013 11:49:56 PM 
I've commented the mouse listener and changed this line g2d.rotate(Math.PI, x, y); //rotate 180 degrees

My problem is how to access correctly the Graphics2d instance and repaint it, because my approach doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to override `paintComponent`?

Comment: @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {.. you code}

Comment: The problem is there is no such method in JFrame ... 
I tried naive graphicalPosDisplayFrame.add(new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D) g;
     g2d.rotate(Math.PI, anchorx, anchory);
    }
   });

But it does not help either.